# understand np.matmul on 1D vectors

Tags: numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication, numpy-ndarray

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [10, 10, 10]
```

np.matmul(a, b) gives 60 as the result.

How does numpy multiply (3,) and (3,) dimension and returns the dot product not outer product (3 * 3) or throw an error "dimension not matching"?

Comment: look at the docs. For 1d arrays it behaves like `dot` and returns the inner 'dot' product. This is a special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is directly from the docs of [`numpy.matmul()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

> - If the first argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by
>     prepending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication
>     the prepended 1 is removed.
> - If the second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by
>     appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication
>     the appended 1 is removed.

---

Thus, the shape of the inputs `a` and `b` are converted to `(1, 3)` and `(3,1)` respectively, during the matrix multiplication.

By the rules of matrix multiplication, we know that:

`1 x 3`   `3 x 1`
      |     |
      --------   ===>   summed over.

Thus, we get the result as a *scalar*.